# Creating drag-and-drop Radar Chart Form

Tags: swift3, ios-charts

I'm trying to figure out how to create a radar chart in iOS where I could drag the points around and then submit the data as a form.

I'm assuming that the form part will be simple - just grab the info from the form object and submit. I'm getting stuck on how to create an ability to drag-and-drop the points on the Radar chart, though.

Is this possible within ios-charts or natively? If not maybe I could find a JS plugin that does it and wrap a web view around it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Daniel's chart library do support radar chart. Please refer below options.

Native charts for iOS https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts 
and for android https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Web:
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#radar-chart
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider [Highchart we have used in one of our product for iOS and Android it works perfectly well.]

Comment: Yes I know that Charts is available for iOS - I have that set up. What I'm trying to enable is the ability to drag-and-drop the points and use that data to submit a form. I haven't figured out a way to do so with Charts.

Comment: I see you mentioned Highcart. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Max, check out draggable plugin http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/3/Draggable%20Points if that is helpful for Spider Web chart.